# How to count the amount of vowels and consonants in a text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to correctly count the number of vowels and consonants in a text file but I am lost currently. I have the other parts that need to be found done.

```
# Home work 4
from string import punctuation

fname = raw_input("Enter name of the file: ")
fvar = open(fname, "r")
punctuationList = "!#$%&'(),.:;?"
numLines = 0
numWords = 0
numChars = 0
numPunc = 0
numVowl = 0
numCons = 0


if line in "aeiou":
    numVowl = + 1
else:
    numCons += 1

for line in fvar:
    wordsList = line.split()
    numLines += 1
    numWords += len(wordsList)
    numChars += len(line)
for punctuation in punctuationList:
    numPunc += 1


print "Lines %d" % numLines
print "Words %d" % numWords
print "The amount of charcters is %d" % numChars
print "The amount of punctuation is %d" % numPunc
print "The amount of vowls is %d" % numVowl
print "The amount of consonants is %d" % numCons
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: As a first step, try writing a function that, given a **string**, returns the number of consonant letters and vowel letters. Then work from there. For example, `count("hello world")` may return `(7, 3)`

Comment: You have the `if line` statement outside the `for line in fvar` loop. How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over all the characters in the line, testing whether they're vowels, consonants, or punctuation.

```
for line in fvar:
    wordsList = line.split()
    numLines += 1
    numWords += len(wordsList)
    numChars += len(line)
    for char in line:
        if char in 'aeiou':
            numVowl += 1
        elif char in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
            numCons += 1
        else:
            numPunc += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('file.txt')]
new_lines = [[sum(b in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz' for b in i), sum(b in "aeiou" for b in i)] for i in f]
total_consonants = sum(a for a, b in new_lines)
total_vowels = sum(b for a, b in new_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function that returns a 3-tuple of the counts you care about when given a string.

```
import string

def count_helper(s) -> ("vowel count", "consonant count", "punctuation count"):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    consonants = set(string.ascii_lowercase).difference(vowels)
    # you could also do set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'), but I recommend this approach
    # because it's more obviously correct (you can't possibly typo and miss a letter)
    c_vowel = c_consonant = c_punctuation = 0
    for ch in s:
        if ch in vowels: c_vowel += 1
        elif ch in consonants: c_consonant += 1
        else: c_punctuation += 1
    return (c_vowel, c_consonant, c_punctuation)
```

Then as you iterate through the file, pass each line to `count_helper`.

```
counts = {'vowels': 0, 'consonants': 0, 'punctuation': 0}
for line in f:
    v, c, p = count_helper(line)
    counts['vowels'] += v
    counts['consonants'] += c
    counts['punctuation'] += p
```

Comment: For fun (and practice) I built this toy program in Haskell https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/0b3ed35e140d000e3ce614d0ce5a327b